# how to set Service account key json as string in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

```
provider "google" {
  project     = "my-project-id"
  region      = "us-central1"
   credentials = *PATH TO SERVICE ACCOUNT KEY FILE*
}
```

in **line 4** I want to store the contents of json as a string instead of the path to the file. Can anyone help me with how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What about using the env variables supported by Terraform to authenticate with GCP ?

See more [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#full-reference)

Comment: Prefer this solution. Or pass the json key file as argument. Don't copy it in plain text, it's a secret, and if you put in in your TF file, you will commit it on GIT and.... Be careful when you use secrets!

Comment: Just wondering on the json key file, how would we then share the json key file with other team members ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
credentials = <<EOF
[Replace this with content of json file]
EOF
```